# How can I rip a DVD-A (DVD-Audio) disc containing music in 5.1 surround sound format?

Tags: music, ripping

1. What application can I use?
2. What audio format should I choose to encode the files?

Comment: I haven't done it, but I would think it would mount like a normal DVD on the linux side.  aac or vob files would contain the media.  vlc plays/transcodes almost anything, ffmpeg plays/transcodes anything if you compile it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this guide

this method actually only extracts the compressed DTS sound of the Video DVD

http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/ripping-dts-5.1-multichannel-audio-from-dvd-a

how to rip the uncompressed multichannel PCM data.

http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/ripping-multichannel-surround-audio-dvd-audio-pcm

.

Comment: Unfortunately, the links have rotted. I have [used DVD Audio Explorer](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2014/08/dealing-with-quadrophonic-dvd-a-files-in-linux/) successfully in the past, but I would be interested if anyone knows a different way.

Comment: [See if Super can do it](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)

Comment: I should probably point out that I'm on Linux and have been using WINE so far, but would prefer a native solution...